# Retaining Data in ASP.NET Page

Tags: asp.net, events, postback, global-variables, pageload

I have a simple ASP.NET page where after the initial page load the user enters a username and a password to two text boxes. Note that I can not use the built-in login control in ASP.NET, as my purpose of using this username and password is slightly different.

Now, I want the user to enter the said two values only once. Afterwards, using those two values I perform several tasks. Now here's the tricky part; since I set the TextMode property of the password text box to 'password', every time a button click occurs it clears the password field, and since every button click event triggers a page load as well, I lose the password data. But I do not want the user to keep entering the password every time he has to click a button.

How can I retain the username and password in my code? If this were a normal .NET Windows Application, I would use a global variable and assign the value the first time and I would have it available to me throughout the life cycle of my program. But how can I do it here?

Please note that this is my very first ASP.NET program, so some code sample would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [Session State](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972429.aspx)

In the session collection you can store and retrieve data for the session to which the user is connected to. A session has a timeout I think its 20 minutes standard.

```
'Save
Session("username") = txtUsername.Text
Session("password") = txtPassword.Text

'Retrieve
Response.Write(Session("username"))
```